# can't send cache limit cheaker and problem in back button session variable still displaying after logout and if i prees back button

Tags: php

HI everyone

1.
As user enter username and password in sign-in-form.php then values are collected in sign-in-action-form.php page and the i am storing username into session variable like this
In database i have a table named employee

```
<a href="logout_file.php">Sign Out</a>
if (username and passwords are matched)
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['employee']['id'] = $row['User_Id'];
$_SESSION['employee']['username'] =$row['Username'];
}
then on each page i am passing logout-file.php link and checking session variable like this

<body bgcolor="white">
<a href="logout_file.php">Sign Out</a>
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['employee']))
{
echo "Your are Logged Out";
exit;
}
else
{
echo "Welcome Mr.".$_SESSION['employee']['username']; //check it
}
?>
Body data like other links
</body>
```

Now on each page i have given links like this

Now listen my problem
on each page i am printing
echo "Welcome Mr.".$_SESSION['employee']['username'];
So think i am on signinactionpage where there other link like show file,upload file etc..
with sign out button now as i click on sign out button i am redirected to login page(no probelm up to here)
But when i press back button (now i am logeed out) then i am again in signinaction form and Mr.Deepak.Narwal is still displaying there why so if i am looed out session destroyed and why this name is displaying..why so

2.
along with this one more error is displaying on each page which contain logout button and this session coading...

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at E:\xampp\htdocs\upload_file.php:6) in E:\xampp\htdocs\upload_file.php on line 7

```
My logout-file.php page is like this
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header ("Location: signinform.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session_start() method should be called at the begin of the file. Try to put it as the first operation that you do in the logout.

Comment: sorry i didnt get what u ant to say...plz explain little bit what u want to say..i am not getting sir where u are saying to put session_start()

Comment: Generally it must be the first operation that you do so put it at the begin of the file.

Comment: Means i have to write code like this on each page

<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['employee']))
{
echo "Your are Logged Out";
exit;
}
else
{
echo "Welcome Mr.".$_SESSION['employee']['username']; //check it
}
?>
<a href="logout_file.php">Sign Out</a>

Logout link should be placed after this session start..

Am i right

Comment: Yes try in this way. Anyway instead of writing the code on each page you should create a single file with that code and then include it at the beginning of every page.

Answer (score 0):

By default, in both MSIE and Firefox, pressing the back button takes the user to a cached page *even if the server explicitly instructed the browser not to cache the contents*.

There are limits to this (but note that when you close some browsers with open tabs, then when it resumes at the same page, it may again use local copies of non0-cacheable content).

To avoid this, then you could imlpement any page where authentication details are submitted as post-redirect-get and also disable form field caching by the browser using autocomplete="off"

C.

Comment: means in each page on form tag i have to write autocomplete="off"